# How to set table heading and data dynamically in angular 2/4 using Ionic 2/3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Presently i am getting the below Dynamic data in json and i am displaying in ionic grid

**JSON data**

```
{Type: "USD",Amount: 131295.21}
{Type: "Master",Amount: 11773.89}

{Type: "PAID",Amount: 51375.3}

{Type: "PAID",Amount: 25558.9}

{Type: "Visa",Amount: 15715.75}

{Type: "ZOM",Amount: 64771.55}
```

and im displaying in html file like below

```
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row >

        <ion-col>
         Type
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col text-right>
          Amount
        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
      <div >
      <ion-row *ngFor="let value of resultData">

        <ion-col>
          {{value.Type}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col text-right>
          {{value.Amount|number:'.2'}}
        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          Total
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col text-right>
          {{TotalAmount|number:'.2'}}
        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
        </div>
    </ion-grid>
```

here mainly below issues i am facing

1. how to set table headers and data dynamical at present i am setting the table heading statically suppose if a table row is not then i have to manually again edit the file
2. If  i set dynamic header and data also along with columns  ,How i can find the totals for that particular columns presently i am looping the **Amount** in future if i get **netamount** then how can i total that
3. If i have to use pipes like For Currency,Date,Time etc how can put it for individual columns

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 3, do you mean individual items on in your object array or do you mean individual interpolated values in your object

Comment: @OliverCooke Suppose in future if i get Column like Date,Currency then for Date i need to use date pipe and for Currency i need to use currency related pipe how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. To set the table headers put in another ngFor for your headers you can get the property names using [`Object.keys(myObject)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys); or you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)
2. If you use the above approach it means you loop for actual content is separate, I would work out the amount in the code behind and interpolate the value in the last column
3. This should be pretty straightforward when you decide to add a date you can add it in

   `<ion-row *ngFor="let value of resultData">
       <ion-col>
           {{value.Type}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col text-right>
           {{value.Amount | currency:'USD':true:'4.2-2'}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col text-right>
           {{value.Date | date:'shortTime'}}
       </ion-col>
   </ion-row>`

Here is a plunker example home it helps https://plnkr.co/edit/Mzv8777npcxVkCmdx4Ka?p=preview

Hope that helps

Comment: but what if i add a column name date is add in future and i have to add a Datepipe for that then how can i do that?

Comment: @TechieBoy That should do the trick you will have to add that yourself it cant be dynamically added as far as im aware

Comment: by using the normal approach i can mention like that but by using the Object.keys(myObject) how can i get individually can u create a plunker plz

Comment: @TechieBoy I've added a plunk